# How typescript creates generic interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to use typescript to realize the following functions?

```js
interface ActionType {
  // how code?
  type: string
};

let actionType: ActionType<{list: any}> = {
  type: 'type',
  list: []
}
```

Comment: What do you mean realize?

Comment: shorry! My English is poor, see code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking about a generic [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

```ts
//              Generic type
//              |      Intersection type
//              ↓      ↓
type ActionType<T> = T & { type: string };

const actionType: ActionType<{list: any[] }> = {
  type: 'type',
  list: []
};
```